# Spectrum of an integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am trying to find the spectrum of the operator $Tf(x)=\int_{0}^{1}(1+x^2y^2)f(y)dy$ in $L^2(0,1)$.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Have you tried looking on the site for "spectrums of integral operators"? It will give you some hints. Besides, if you have attempted the question or seem similar questions then mention them. It also helps to know your background so people can tailor their responses to your background. Example : have you seen this in some textbook or exam?

Comment: I have tried to look for eigenvalues but I don't know how to solve the equation Tf=lf.

Comment: Please make sure you converse with the answerer below until you understand his answer completely. Thanks for mentioning your issue, it is exactly what was tackled in the attempt below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $Tf=\lambda f $ is equivalent to $$\lambda f(x)=\int_0^1f(y)dy+x^2\int_0^1y^2f(y)dy$$ Hence either

- $\lambda\ne0$ and $f(x)=Ax^2+B$; then the equation above becomes $$\lambda(Ax^2+B)=\tfrac{1}{3}A+B+(\tfrac{1}{5}A+\tfrac{1}{3}B)x^2$$ Comparing coefficients gives $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}&\frac{1}{3}\\\frac{1}{3}&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix}=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\end{pmatrix}$, so $\lambda$ equals the eigenvalues $\lambda,\mu$ of this matrix and $(A,B)$ their eigenvectors.
- $\lambda =0$ then $\int_0^1f=0=\int_0^1y^2f(y)dy$. In this case, there are an infinite number of linearly independent solutions for $f$, in fact any function of the type $f(x):=g(x)-(A+Bx^2)$ for $g\in L^2[0,1]$ can satisfy these two equations if the right $A,B$ are chosen.

Hence the spectrum is $\{0,\lambda,\mu\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I have calculated the point spectrum and it is empty.  I have a last question, is Range(T)=span{1, x^2}? If so I can conclude that T is compact so the spectrum of T is {0}. Is this correct?

Comment: @giuseppeknecht The spectrum can never be empty for a Banach space! See the modified answer.